# mysql join count lines in third table

Tags: mysql, join, count, multiple-tables

I have three mySQL-tables like this:

```
client                   network                   activities
\_id                     \_id                      \_id
\_name                   \_name                    \_client_id
\_[...]                  \[...]                    \_[...]
\_network_id
```

Now I want to have the following result:

```
client.*, network.name, number_of_activities_for_each_client
```

Actually I have this select-statement:

```
select client.*, network.name 
from client 
left join network 
on client.network_id = network.id
```

How do I extend the statement? I would also like to see all clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*, n.name, COUNT(a.id) number_of_activities_for_each_client
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN network n
ON n.id = c.network_id
LEFT JOIN activities a
ON a.client_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: You may want to change it to `COALESCE(COUNT(a.id), 0)` in case there are no rows in the activities table for a client.

Comment: no, I see no need to add that function, it returns 0 if no records found : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cdb7/1

Comment: Oh... I was like 99% sure it returned null. I don't know where I got that idea from then.